# ajax url redirection controller in cakephp 2.x

Tags: jquery, ajax, cakephp-2.x

I am making message board like messenger and uses cakephp 2.x and ajax request to it.

This is the url where I am performing the send new message and uses the send function in my controller

[SendNewMessageUrl](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oOZNH.png)

So you'll notice that my url in ajax '../messages/send' is visiting the send function and executes perfectly

```
     $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: '../messages/send',
            cache: false,
            data: {
                'id': id,
                'message': message
            },
            success: function(result) {
                alert(result);
                window.location.href = "../messages/";
            },      
            error: function (response, desc, exception) {
                alert(exception);
            }
        });
```

So in this image is a url of my reply message module and you'll notice that there are 2 parameters that were added in messages controller

[ReplyMessage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fkJ4p.png)

This is my MessagesController

```
public function send() {

            $this->request->trustProxy = true;
            $clientIp = $this->request-> clientIp();

                if($this->request->is('ajax')){
                    $this->request->data['Message']['to_id'] = $this->request->data['id'];
                    $this->request->data['Message']['from_id'] = $this->Auth->user('id');
                    $this->request->data['Message']['content'] = $this->request->data['message'];
                    $this->request->data['Message']['created_ip'] = $this->request->data['Message']['modified_ip'] = $this->request-> clientIp();

                    $this->Message->set($this->request->data);

                    $response = $this->Message->save();

                    if($response){
                        echo 'Message sent';
                    }
                    else{
                        echo 'Something went wrong';
                    }
                    exit();
                }
        }
```

From here http://localhost/messenger/messages/conversation/2' (reply message)

What I want to achieve is I want to reuse the send function from the controller and how will I properly assign or initialize a url value to ajax url?

Comment: Why put the URLs in images? Just copy+paste them in to the question

Comment: Because the page will not help in my issue. All I wanted is how will I set the ajax url  @RoryMcCrossan

Comment: If they're useful enough to include, include the details here. If they add nothing, don't include them at all. Many people won't bother clicking external links, which hurts your chances of getting an answer.